# Extend the Eclipse Project->Clean... Extension point to trigger a method and add some code like validation etc

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Recently I need a function that when click the Project->clean item from the Eclipse menu and then do a re-validation to do some checking, so I need to add some code in a method which is triggered by clicking the Project-clean item. And I look up some materials, and seems that Builder and Nature can handle this, and I also try to add some extension in my plugin.xml like,

```
 <extension id="nature" name="Nature" point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
     <runtime>
           <run class="xxx.xxx.xxx"></run>
     </runtime>
     <builder id="MyDesigner.builder">
     </builder>
</extension>

<extension id="builder" name="Builder" point="org.eclipse.core.resources.builders">
   <builder hasNature="true" isConfigurable="false">
        <run class="xxx.xxx.MyBuilder"></run>
   </builder>
</extension>
```

And in the MyBuilder class, I add some code in the method "protected void clean(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {...}"
                After that I run the Eclipse Application to start the sub-studio, and then click the Project->Clean, but  the clean method doesn't trigger? So is this way OK to achieve that? Or does anyone have any idea for it? Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: Have you added the nature to the project?

Comment: Yes, I added nature and builder both, so this way can work to invoke the clean method in MyBuilder class?